# Excel - INDEX + MATCH + COUNTIF function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

- 5 columns of 10,000+ rows
- Column A= employee name
- Only column A is unique
- Columns B-D are the employee's reporting hierarchy, top to bottom from left to right
- Column B,C,D = Senior VP name, VP name, Supervisor name
- Column E = Manager mapping (where I need help, details below)

I need to map in column E the employee's manager based on the conditions below:

- Column E = Column B unless the count of employees mapped to that Senior VP exceeds 1,000 -- if so, then map to Column C (VP)
- Column E = Column D if the count of employees mapped to that VP exceeds 374

Using a simpler example below, let's say we need to match column E to B unless the count of cell value in Column B exceeds 3 then match to column C. If count of cell value is column C exceeds 2 then match to column D.

[see example sheet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Qsp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

`=IF(AND(COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,B2)>=3,COUNTIFS($C$1:C1,C2)>=2),D2,IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,B2)>=3,C2,B2))`

[image]